# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random._pcg64'

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random._pcg64'
When using both pycharm and vscode, I get this error when starting to run any script with a numpy import. Numpy is updated to the most recent version.

I've tried on both pycharm and vscode. I've run multiple scripts all with the numpy import and they all raise this error. I haven't been able to find anything online about it. What is likely the problem here and how might I fix it?
The full error code from pycharm is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\Physics Project\working3d.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._pcg64 import PCG64, PCG64DXSM
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random._pcg64'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure what was wrong, but I think it had to do with my conda environments being set up in a weird way. I reinstalled anaconda and set up new environments and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstalling NumPy to ensure a clean installation.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```